# PHP: Transparent PNG to clipping mask

Tags: php, image, imagemagick, gd

How can i convert a transparent PNG to a Black White Mask in PHP?
Is there a special function?
[image] [image]

Comment: You probably want `separateImageChannel(3)`, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.separateimagechannel.php

Answer (score 1):

If you have a transparent PNG and want the binary mask just extract the alpha channel in Imagemagick 6.

```
convert image.png -alpha extract mask.png
```

If on Imagemagick 7, change convert to magick